# How do i read a BufferedFile using read(ubyte[] buffer) when the buffer length is set at runtime?

Tags: d

I have a binary file that is really a stack of files, the format is:

```
lengh_of_subfile,subfile
```

`length_of_subfile` is a 64-bit integer. I can read the `long` no problem but when I try to create a buffer for the subfile I get compile errors saying it cannot be read at compile time. What am I missing? I've written an identical extraction tool in erlang, PHP and C#... D is throwing me for a loop.

```
void main(string args[]) {
    Stream file = new BufferedFile(args[1], FileMode.In);
    int counter = 0;
    while(file.position < file.size) {
        ulong len;
        file.read(len);
        ubyte[len] ogg;
        file.read(ogg);
        string outname = getcwd() ~ "/" ~ to!string(counter) ~ ".ogg";
        Stream oggout = new BufferedFile(outname, FileMode.OutNew);
        oggout.write(ogg);
        writefln("Creating file " ~ to!string(counter) ~ ".ogg");
        counter++;
    }   
}
```

Comment: You need a [dynamic array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363728/d-dynamic-array-initialization-stride-and-the-index-operation). (I have no idea how, though, because I don't program in D)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of

```
        ubyte[len] ogg;
```

write

```
        ubyte[] ogg = new ubyte[len];
```

Answer (score 2):

slice off what you want to fill

```
ubyte[1024*8] ogg;
ogg=ogg[0..len]
file.read(ogg);
```

or use a loop to do the copying (as a 2^64 byte array wont fit in memory)

```
ubyte[1024*16] ogg;
while(len>0 && (int read=file.read(ogg[0..$>len?len:$]))!=0){
    oggout.write(ogg[0..read]);
    len-=read;//len is the amount still to be read
}
```

side note `writeln("Creating file ",counter, ".ogg");` is more efficient than concat then write (the java way) because it doesn't create useless strings (and creating the format string at runtime is asking for a error sooner or later on the first `%` you don't account for)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a array with dynamic length or just use new to create a new ubyte array:

```
new ubyte[len]
```